# Customized Reactive Component interact with SelectedFilters

Tags: reactivesearch

It took me quite a long time trying to find a solution, still no solution.
Take the official example to illustrate:

https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/v3/advanced/reactivecomponent.html

I can add `showFilter` and `filterLabel` property to the parent `ReactiveCompnent`, however, after user picked the color, how to notify the `SelectedFilters` component about the value picked? how to get notified when user clear the color in the `SelectedFilters`?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use custom `SelectedFilters` with `ReactiveComponent`. We are constantly working on the improvement of docs. I will add the respective link which might help you understand the usage of `ReactiveComponent`.

For now, you can check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zrj740oj6). I have created tab-based filtering using `ReactiveComponent` with custom `SelectedFilters`.

Hope this helps!